# choose a few id from db C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a database and excel file

And I want to export strings to excel

How to export strings with 1 id I know

The code you can see below

```
_Hours = Rep.Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectGroupID == 4).Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectType == 1).Sum(o => (decimal?)o.TaskEfforts) ?? 0m,
```

But how I can choose several id's?

This does not work

```
 _Hours = Rep.Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectGroupID == 4).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 10).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 17).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 18).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 19).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 21).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 24).Where(o => o.ProjectDescriptionID == 26).Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectType == 1).Sum(o => (decimal?)o.TaskEfforts) ?? 0m,
```

I know, that it is an error, but how can I choose some ID's?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: use `||` to OR them together. use only one `Where`

Comment: I need not OR, but AND
So i use &&
And it is not work too

Comment: Array has a method called contains and it's supported in EF so new up an array or a list and use contains.

Comment: "I need not OR, but AND" - no, you don't. The ProjectDescriptionID can't be 21 *and* 24 for the same project. You want any project where the description ID is 21 *or* the description ID is 24 *or* the description ID is 26 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is because each where clause is working on a subset of data that the previous one put out.

Use a list for your LINQ query's boolean logic.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>{ 10, 17, 13, 7 };

_Hours = Rep.Where(o => ids.Contains(o.Projects.ProjectGroupID)).Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectType == 1).Sum(o => (decimal?)o.TaskEfforts) ?? default(int);
```

By manipulating the boolean this way, you can essentially convert a list of ints into a list of objects.

For your second where clause, I see you're needing a different attribute to restrict the list even further.  This would work, since each where clause operates on the results of the first, but for the reader's sake it should be a &&.

```
_Hours = Rep.Where(o => ids.Contains(o.Projects.ProjectGroupID) && o.Projects.ProjectType == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! As mentioned in the comments, you can use the || (OR) operator to select the `o` object if the id matches. In this case, you only need one Where. Here is your example written out:

```
_Hours = Rep.Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectGroupID == 4 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 10 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 17 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 18 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 19 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 21 ||  o.ProjectDescriptionID == 24 || o.ProjectDescriptionID == 26).Where(o => o.Projects.ProjectType == 1).Sum(o => (decimal?)o.TaskEfforts) ?? 0m,
```

Edit: Didn't realize ProjectType property check at end of ORs. Made it it's own WHERE selector

Comment: It's possible that the ProjectGroupId and ProjectType parts *should* be effectively anded, either in the same Where clause or by multiple Where calls. It's hard to tell based on the description.

Comment: Good catch. Didn't realize the ProjectType check at the end. You are correct that those should be ANDed together by using another Where selector. Thanks. Edited post.